# Is the probability either G or H will occur but not both occurring equal to (s-r +0)?

Tags: probability

Suppose event H is a subset of G, where everything in the event H is contained in G but not vise-versa, the probability that H occurs is r and the probability G occurs is s, what's the probability that either G or H will occur, but not both occurring?

The probability that G will occur but H will not occur is (s-r).

The probability that H will occur while G not occurring is zero.

[image: P]

Comment: That seems a reasonable approach.  What precisely are you asking us?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.